# jquery - copy input text onblur if another input is also blank

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to copy text from several inputs on the blur of one input IF a destination input is also blank, but can't get it working.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var n = $('#Zip1').val;
var m = $('#Cname').val;
$('#Zip1').on('focus', function () {
if (n.length === 0 && m.length === 0) {
    $('#Cname').val($('#FName1').val && ' ' && $('#LName1').val);
    $('#Address').val($('#Address1').val);
    $('#City').val($('#City1').val);
    $('#Zip').val($('#Zip1').val);
}
});
```

Working (not quite) example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZVTt/1/

** ---------- UPDATE -----------------------**

Thanks everyone!  Here is the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZVTt/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `val()` not `val`. `val` just gives you the function reference not the executed value of the function.

```
var n = $('#Zip1').val();
var m = $('#Cname').val();
$('#Zip1').on('focus', function () {
    if (n.length === 0 && m.length === 0) {
        $('#Cname').val($('#FName1').val() && ' ' && $('#LName1').val());
        $('#Address').val($('#Address1').val());
        $('#City').val($('#City1').val());
        $('#Zip').val($('#Zip1').val());
    }

});
```

Another thing is you are doing this operation on the focus of `zip1` at the source text box at that time value will be empty in the beginning so nothing will be copies. You have to re focus again on the zip1 textbox to copy. Not sure if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly used `val()` function, change `val` to `val()`

```
var n = $('#Zip1').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the mistake on `val()` usage as already been pointed out. I think instead of when `Zip` is focused it should be when the `donation` field is focused and that's the time that it should be copied to the Billing Address like:

```
$('#Amount1').on('focus', function () {
 // More code here...
 }):
```

Additionally you were using `maxlength=255` for all fields. I think you should be discreet in using that one like for Zip Code, I don't think you need 255 as length on that probably 5 would be appropriate.

See my [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdy_dot/QqS9v/)